# Rules of creating Stored Procedures and Functions for notification

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sqldependency

While using `SqlDependency` and `SqlMonitor` to get notified of database alterations I know there are [certain](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181122%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) rules to construct the query.

What I am curious about is what is the required structure of `Stored Procedure`'s; as far as I can understand for making a simple `SELECT` query, by following the rules I can make it work with sql notification service.

1. What happens when there are control flows (`if`'s, `else`'s or `while`'s) in `SP`? Is there any rule set?
2. Does same rules apply on `Function`'s too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Creating a Query for Notification](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181122%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

> When a command that registers a notification contains more than one statement, the Database Engine creates a notification for each statement in the batch.

So if you have control flow (if, else, while etc) then the path that was actually executed is the path that sets up the notifications. If a branch is not taken then no notification is set up, as no statement is executed in that branch. If a loop executes a statement repeatedly, a separate notification is set up for every execution.

As for UDFs the only one that matter are those that are basically inlined in the statement, since pretty much any other UDF would make the query invalid for notifications. Those inlined UDFs act as if you had written the expanded function definition in the statement. In other words, they don't change anything vis-a-vis the notificaiton. Is the *statement* that matters.

The gist of it is that only SELECT can set up a notification. When you execute a SP (or a batch) the notification is not set up for the 'SP' per-se, but instead the notifications are set up for each SELECT statement executed, as is being executed.

Comment: So when the statements are valid for notification concept, there is nothing to stop me from getting the notifications. It won't make any difference for me to get notified from one statement in the SP or from  the other. Did I get you right?

Comment: AFAIK you may get *many* notifications. If you have a valid statement and an invalid one int he same SP, you will immediately get the invalid notification, and later you may get an update notification, on the *same* `SqlDependency`. I haven't played much with SPs I reckon, you better test it.